# Ubuntu 20.04 does not login after entering username and password

Tags: nvidia, sound, dell, 20.04

I have a dell g31590. I cannot login. When I enter into tty using ctrl+alt+f4 I am returned with an error `[75.253144] sof-audio-pci 00000:00:1f:3 error:no reply expected, received 0x0.`

I have nvidia drivers 440 running. I have tried recovery mode from grub. There are no broken packages using dpkg. Running nvidia-smi I can see no issues.

Any ideas what this issue is?

Comment: Can you specify how did you install the drivers in the first place.

Comment: I ran  1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa 
         2. sudo apt-get update 3. sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

Comment: try it once, it might help  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231410/cant-log-in-on-ubuntu-20-04/1246081#1246081

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It appears these lines are already commented out. I uncommented and I could log in. Thank you

Comment: Although input freezes shortly after logging in.

Comment: I purged all nvidia drivers. No issues so far. I will probably downgrade versions.