# Ubuntu 20.04 does not login with Xorg

Tags: 20.04, login, xorg

The login on my Ubuntu 20.04 suddenly stopped working. After entering the password, it get stuck at a purple screen with the mouse pointer. This is not a fresh install and it was working ok until past boot.

I installed the `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` package (from what I searched on the internet the display manager is often the problem in this case) and was able to login selecting the `GNOME` option on the login screen. It does not work with `GNOME (on Xorg)`, however. I think the default `Ubuntu` option (instead of `GNOME`) also uses Xorg, so I think the problem is within Xorg.

I tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xauth` but that didn't solve the problem.

Most of the existing answers suggest installing another display manager ([Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)), which I'm trying to avoid because I really like using the default interface. Whereas others have problems with Nvidia drivers ([Login loop after installing 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229821/login-loop-after-installing-20-04.)), which is also not my case because I only have an intel onboard video card.

I know that's an often question but I could not find a solution for this in Ubuntu 20.04. Any suggestions to solve this (apparent) Xorg problem? I'm not very experienced with that so I might be missing something simple here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yeah I have the same problem!