# Ubuntu login loop 20.04

Tags: 20.04, login

I was having no trobules with Ubuntu... until i enabled the option: "Automatic login"

When my computer turns on it show me the login screen (Should not 'cause i've enabled the automatic login option), well, i write my password and Ubuntu ask my password again in a infinite loop, when i try to turn off my pc Ubuntu says: "Another account is using this computer" and shows my user wich i'm trying to login... so what?

I don't kwno what to do, it's all i can describe here, i have not trying anithing, mi PC is new, Ubuntu is installed on a NVMe disk and i have a Nvidia 2060RTX

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Login loop after installing 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229821/login-loop-after-installing-20-04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/01/login-loop-auto-login-enabled-in-ubuntu-19-10-with-nvidia-driver/