# Login loop, terminal login problem

Tags: boot

I'm stuck in a login loop ( ubuntu 22.04) which after opening the terminal and keying my password keeps on displaying invalid password. Am stuck, Can someone please help me?
I have tried loging in using the terminal but after i try inputting my password, it simply displays invalid password of which I'm 100% sure it's the right password. Am confused since all the solutions I've read require me to login using the terminal.

Comment: Password is not shown when you type it (not even dots or asterisks. nothing) ... Just type your password and press Enter.

Comment: Does it *really* display "invalid password"? The login program usually doesn't divulge that much information - it just says "login incorrect"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Login loop after installing 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229821/login-loop-after-installing-20-04)